# Wie entstand aus "Sicht" die "Zuversicht"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, history, prefix

Schon länger frage ich mich, wie man die Etymologie von *"Zuversicht"* erkärt. Im Duden wird knapp aufgeführt

> mittelhochdeutsch **zuoversiht**, althochdeutsch **zuofirsiht** <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zuversicht)</sup>

und auch das [Etymologische Wörterbuch nach Pfeiffer](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=zuversicht&view=1) betätigt dies, wie auch die Etymologie aus *"sehen"*:

> **Zuversicht** f. ‘Vertrauen in die Zukunft’, ahd. *zuofirsiht* ‘ehrfurchtsvolles Aufschauen, Hoffen’ (um 1000), mhd. *zuoversiht*.

Es ist also ein altes Wort, bei dem es scheint, als handele es sich um eine doppelte Präfigierung mit *"zu-"* und *"ver-"*. Nun haben aber *"zusehen"* und *"Versehen"* eine ganz andere Bedeutung. Allenfalls *"Vorsicht"* hätte noch eine gewisse Bedeutungsähnlichkeit, aber daraus scheint es sich nicht abzuleiten.

Wie erkärt man sich die Bildung von *"Zuversicht"*? Stimmt meine Vermutung einer doppelten Präfigierung überhaupt?

Comment: Wenn du `Zukunft` und `vor` ebenfalls im etymologischen Wörterbuch nachschlägst, dann landest du bei den beiden Präfixen von Zuversicht: zuo und fir. Es scheint also durch die Entwicklung hindurch eine doppelte Präfigierung zu sein.

Comment: @Toscho: cool, dann scheint es tatsächlich so zu sein. Jetzt fehlt also nur noch die Logik hin zur Zuversicht. :)

Comment: Wieso? Es ist eine VORausSICHT in die ZUKUNFT.

Comment: @Toscho, dann wären die beiden Kommentare doch schon eine schöne Antwort, oder?

Comment: Ja, aber ich bin kein Etymologe und mir dieser Erklärung nicht sicher.

Comment: @Toscho: ich habe mich auf Dein Kommentar hin auf die Suche nach *fir-sicht* gemacht und bin auf dieses ausgestorbene Wort gestoßen: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF12813 - das ist wohl eng mit *Vorsicht* verwandt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zuversicht ist ein Substantiv zu "sich zu jemandem versehen", was so viel bedeutet wie "auf jemanden vertrauen", also eine positive Sicht in die Zukunft (siehe [etymologisches Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm](http://dwb.uni-trier.de/de/)).

Comment: aber woher kommt das "Jemand" ?